# Is it possible to color sperm cells so they look more clear under a microscope?

Tags: reproduction, staining

Im working on something that requires me to check the velocity of a sperm cell under a microscope but I imagine it would be very hard for a program to keep track of the sperm cells.

Comment: You can check this http://www.vivo.colostate.edu/hbooks/pathphys/reprod/semeneval/morph.html